# Can you identify the name of this battery discharging plug (photo attached)?

Tags: batteries, connector, identification, lithium-ion, charging

I am trying to source the male/female sides of this connector that fits on a 48V Lithium Ion battery. Can you please identify the name of this type of connector?

[image: Connector image]

Comment: You can ask questions like this in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/).

Comment: @Hamed:  This type of question is [in topic here.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines)

Comment: How big is it? Can you add rough dimensions?  Also, the size and shape of the outline looks a bit like the IEC power cord (with different things inside). Does it match?

Comment: @JackB: it is around 5 cm X 3 cm.

Comment: That makes it about the size of an IEC C13/C14 connector, and the outline is a good match.  I can't identify it, but "non-standard IEC connector" or "non-standard kettle cord" might be a good google term for further searching.